# Cannot convert expression type to return type

Tags: c#, generics, variance

I have the following method that works:

```
public Option<IAppSettings> GetFirst<T>() where T : IAppSettings
{
  return _sources.Where(x=>x.GetType() == typeof(T)).FirstOption();
}

List<IAppSettings> _sources;
```

But, I want to change the signature to:

```
public Option<T> GetFirst<T>() where T : IAppSettings
```

Note that I am returning the generic `T` instead of `IAppSettings`

I am getting the error (truncated types):

> Cannot convert expression type `Option<IAppSettings>` to `Option<T>`

I know this has something to do with generics, but admittedly suck at them....I've tried the different means of `in`, `out`, `interface`, `delegate`...but none worked as this is a method on a non-generic class using an instance variable.

Is this even possible?

**Updated thoughts**

Do I have to change the type specifications in `Option`? If so, I am guessing it has to be `Option<in T>`? I say that only because Scala's `Option` is typed as `Option[+A]` I have the source for `Option`, but it is a pain to change and push up...so figured I would ask here first, but will try that next

This `Option` is coming from [my fork of scalesque](https://github.com/JustinPihony/scalesque/blob/master/Scalesque.net40/Option.cs)

Comment: It might depend on what kind of generics admit Option no? is applied the same?

Comment: It is hard to tell with only the small snippets. For example, does the containing class also contain a generic T argument? As in, `public class Parent<T>{}` ? In this case, that generic type could be affecting the method.

Comment: @TravisJ I said that the containing class is not generic. I did just update to  make clear that `sources` is a `List<IAppSettings>`, though

Comment: What happens if you add .OfType<T>() before .FirstOption() ?

Comment: @Glorfindel That fixed it! Submit as the answer and I will accept

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for the [`Enumerable.OfType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) method. This should replace your `Where()` method.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx

The problem you're getting is that simply doing an "if" check on the type will not actually cast it to `T`; once it passes that filtering, the collection objects are still only known to be type `IAppSettings`. The C# standard function I mentioned will do that for you though.

Comment: I can create a separate ticket, but was curious if you know why I need the OfType? T is constrained to be an IAppSetting, so it should be automatically converted. Is there some usecase I am not thinking of that would break if this were implemented?

Comment: `Where`'s definition is to take a lambda that takes the collection's type and returns a Boolean. Its return type is always a generic collection of the same type as that of the collection it's operating on, and no more specific than that. It doesn't analyze the lambda you gave it to figure out what precise type you're able to return (heck, the lambda could be a variable). If you Where clause was `x -> x.toString().contains("cheese")` then it would also do nothing to increase type specificness; you'd still just have an IAppSettings collection, not a T collection.

Comment: I realize that, but T is constrained to be an IAppSettings, so, it returns an IAppSettings and expects a T:IAppSettings.

Comment: And? What does T have to do with the return type of `Where()`? `Where()` does not change the collection's type; so if you called `GetFirst<VerySpecificAppSettings>()`, and returned `_sources`, it would fail to compile, because you don't know for sure that _sources only contains `VerySpecificAppSettings`; you just know that it contains `IAppSettings`.

Comment: True, variance always gets my head all screwed up. That and Liskov are my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add .OfType() before .FirstOption().